# Abstract class in Java - method overriding

Tags: java

I have started learning Java, and have come across this example, on this [page](http://www.oraclestudy.com/sample-questions/oracle-1z0-808-certification-sample-questions-and-answers):

```
abstract class Writer {
 public static void write() {
 System.out.println("Writing...");
 }
}
class Author extends Writer {
 public static void write() {
 System.out.println("Writing book");
 }
}
public class Programmer extends Writer {
 public static void write() {
 System.out.println("Writing code");
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Writer w = new Programmer();
 w.write();
 }
}
```

Of the options available for the result of this code, it says that the right answer is:

```
Writing...
```

How does it work exactly then, I thought the methods we write in the class that extends abstract class override the methods in the abstract class, but here the answer suggest otherwise.

Comment: There is no method overriding with `static` methods .

Comment: So, if this methods  were not static then it would override?

Comment: Yes it would override.